# Does a subclass use parent constructor if one isn't defined in the subclass?

Tags: java, class, constructor

If I have a subclass that doesn't have a constructor defined but in the superclass there is one defined, will the subclass use that constructor when the subclass object is instantiated?

Comment: No. only the invocation of the constructor of the subclass uses the parent constructor. the class itself doesn't. And, yes, every single constructor call calls the constructor of it's parent class

Comment: if you do not explicitly create a constructor yourself, it will use the default one which is `Sub() { super(); }`. This obviously only works if the parent class has a no-arg constructor. If not, Java will **not compile** your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a subclass use parent constructor if one isn't defined in the subclass?

That depends on what you mean by "use." If you mean, does the default constructor for a child class call the parent constructor, then yes, it does (more below). If you mean, is a default constructor matching whatever parameters the parent constructor has created automatically, then no, not in the general case.

When you don't declare any constructors for a child class, the [*default constructor*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) is supplied for you. It always looks like this

```
/*same access modifier as the class*/ Child() {
    super();
}
```

Base classes have a default as well, which looks the same but just doesn't have `super();`.

So if the parent class has a no-arguments constructor (explicitly, or via the default) then the child class's default constructor will successfully use it. But if there's a constructor defined in the parent class that requires an argument, then the child class won't compile, because the `super()` in the default constructor doesn't match a constructor in the parent class.

Compare this, which works:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent() { // I could have left this off, since it's the default for a
    }                 // base class; it's here for emphasis
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}
```

with this (added a `String` param to the `Parent` constructor), which fails:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent(String s) {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}
```

The second one fails with:

```
class Child extends Parent {
^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

If **no constructor** is written in a class, actually a *default constructor* is added, which can be seen in the byte code:

```
class A {
}
```

will generate code for:

```
class A extends Object {
    A() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Every constructor must call a constructor of the parent class as the first statement.
Again here there is an implicit call to `super()`.

```
class B extends A {
    B() {
        System.out.println();
    }
    B(int n) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

will generate code for

```
class B extends A {
    B() {
        super(); // A()
        System.out.println();
    }
    B(int n) {
        super(); // A()
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This means one can get an error, that no (overloaded) constructor is available for the given argument types.

An other point is, that in general the statement `super();` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an empty child class that extends the parent:

```
public class TestChild extends TestParent{

}
```

And the parent looks like:

```
public class TestParent {

private String testStr;

public TestParent() {
    this.testStr = "I exist in the child class!";
}

public String getTestStr() {
    return testStr;
}

public void setTestStr(String testStr) {
    this.testStr = testStr;
}
}
```

And you create an object of the child in the main and print it out with:

```
    TestChild test = new TestChild();
    System.out.println(test.getTestStr());
```

The result will print out:

```
I exist in the child class!
```

This happens because the child class will automatically call the no-arg constructor of the `super` class.  So you do not explicitly need a constructor in the child class as it will automatically generate to you a default constructor.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase.

Comment: @MC Emperor Yeah, I'll change that, whipped it up really quick and forgot.  Thanks!